# Apache camel to use the classic xml configuration directly in camel-main to run in standalone

Tags: java, apache-camel

In Apache Camel 3.17+, is there a way to include xml DSL route definition directly, so I can run it in standalone.

With JAVA DSL the java route configuration can be added to the Main() context using `addRoutesBuilders()`, like in below example.

I wanted to add the xml context directly to the Main().

```java
public class MainApp {

    public static void main(String... args) throws Exception {
        Main main = new Main();
        main.configure().addRoutesBuilder(new MyRouteBuilder());
        main.run(args);
    }
}
```

```java
public class MyRouteBuilder extends RouteBuilder {

    public void configure() {

     from("direct:start")
            .to("mock:result");
    }
}
```

Is it possible to use `camel-main` for routes defined in xml based DSL using camelContext tags?

Below is the sample xml

```xml
<!-- spring xmlns added removed here for make the xml brief -->
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"....

<camelContext xmlns = "http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">
   <route>
      <from uri = "direct:input"/>
      <log message = "log message for demo"/>
      <to uri = "file:src/main/resources/data/"/>
   </route>
</camelContext>
```

Comment: For my understanding Camels XML-DSL requires you to use either **Spring-framework** or **OSGi blueprints**. If you look your xml closely you can see that it includes `http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans` which tells us that the file is intended to be used with Spring-frameworks dependency injection feature.

Comment: With camel-main you cannot use the `CamelContext` XML tag. But you can use the shortened `routes` tag. Take a look at this example project to see how it works https://github.com/apache/camel-examples/tree/main/examples/main-xml.

Comment: There is an example in git [camel-spring-xml](https://github.com/apache/camel-examples/tree/main/examples/spring), where we can use the Main directly. had to explore this option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

we can use below dependency in `pom.xml`.

- `camel-spring-xml` &
- `camel-spring-main`

```xml
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
      <artifactId>camel-spring-main</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
      <artifactId>camel-spring</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

- MainApp.java

```java
import org.apache.camel.spring.Main;

public class MainApp {

    public static void main(String... args) throws Exception {
        Main main = new Main();
        main.run(args);
    }

}
```

- To scan the spring bean based configuration automatically, by creating the xml in `resources/META-INF/spring/*.xml`.